# How to make ol draw interaction only accept drawings that snaps to a given feature

Tags: openlayers-3

How would i make the Draw interaction do the following:

Draw a linestring, but only accept the first point when it is snapped (connected) to an existing feature/geometry?

Is there a way to cancel the mouse click, start draw when a condition is not true?

Comment: There is a `condition` option when init your draw interaction. You may pass a function to it to return true/false and thus cancel the event. check the doc here -->http://openlayers.org/en/v3.19.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html

Comment: But from this, you dont have access to the current feature being drawn? From this condition function, how do you tell if its the first point of the linestring ?

Comment: You can get the feature type drawn using `this.type_` within the condition function or `this.sketchCoords_` to get the coordinates and do you checks. If you need a sample let me know.